# append and addClass to animate failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, animate.css

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
  $('#ticketsDemosss').append($('<li>').text('my li goes here')).addClass('fadeIn');
});
```

```html
<link href="http://s.mlcdn.co/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl id="viewbranchcontact-2">
  <ul id="ticketsDemosss" class="tickets">
    <!-- add LI here -->
  </ul>
</dl>

<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

any idea why above code won't work? I used animate.css a library to try to fade in my `li` upon insert but it has flicks.

https://jsfiddle.net/to9fs7t4/

Comment: Short answer `$('<li>').text('my li goes here').appendTo($('#ticketsDemosss')).hide().fadeIn(2000);`

Comment: @vinayakj hw wants to use `animate.css` not simple jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the class `animated` too.

Read the [docs](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css#usage).

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
  $('#ticketsDemosss').append($('<li>').text('my li goes here').addClass('animated fadeIn'));
});
```

```html
<link href="http://s.mlcdn.co/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl id="viewbranchcontact-2">
  <ul id="ticketsDemosss" class="tickets">
    <!-- add LI here -->
  </ul>
</dl>

<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Correct it to `$('#ticketsDemosss').append($('<li>').text('my li goes here').addClass('animated fadeIn'));`

Comment: @vinayakj Thanks again :)

Comment: Eunice Chia, Have you tried this? If it solve your problem, please accept it, so it will help to other people.

Answer (score 0):

So your code isnt working because by default `.append` method appends the element & shows it, so your `addClass(fadeIn)` wont have any effect, second you are adding to ul rather to li

Try below code, corrected code of @Mosh Feu

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
  $('#ticketsDemosss').append($('<li>').text('my li goes here')
                                       .addClass('animated fadeIn')
                             );
});
```

```html
<link href="http://s.mlcdn.co/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<dl id="viewbranchcontact-2">
  <ul id="ticketsDemosss" class="tickets">
    <!-- add LI here -->
  </ul>
</dl>

<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: could have just edited his code instead of writing it as you own answer

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri If you have seen closely, I had commented that too, but seems he might be busy, so posted the answer, because its more about OP(prime subject here), should get what needed.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you use addClass on `#ticketsDemosss` right after appending **to `#ticketsDemosss`** a li element. What you're looking to achieve is to use addClass on the new li element right before/after appending the li element.

Also, when you addClass you should have `animated` class in addition to the desired animation class. i.e. `addClass('fadeIn animated')`

See the jsfiddle update on this link, I've also added the animate.css for you to see it functions and play with it: https://jsfiddle.net/to9fs7t4/1/